# How to use scipy's local sphinx documentation?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-sphinx

On my Linux computer, I have built `scipy` from [source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy) via the command

```
python setup.py build_sphinx
```

what has generated a bunch of `rst` files in the `scipy/doc/source/generated` folder.

But how do I access this documentation? Do I have to generate html files before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) is intended to be (mostly) readable as source, but it is probably best rendered as HTML for human eyes using [docutils](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks for your time. Well, one can read rst - files, but I am not sure about following links and so on. For my particular problem I have found that sphinx generates a `Makefile` in `scipy/doc`. Then the html files are compiled having launched `make html` in this folder.